Como soluciono este evento en tkinter?
Hola a todos hice una función para crear un label dinámico que puedes mover dentro del frame, y ahora quiero cambiar su tamaño solo en el eje y cuando presionas alguna esquina del label, intenté preguntar en el chat gpt y me dio una función, pero esta función tiene un problema. El problema es que cuando presionas en la esquina de la etiqueta, intentas cambiar el tamaño de la etiqueta, se agranda abruptamente y ya no puedes mover la etiqueta y ocupa todo el frame. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
este es mi código:
def principal_body_controls(self):
    self.label = tk.Label(self.principal_body, bg="green", width=30, height=3)
    self.label.place(x=0, y=0)

    def arrastrar(event):
        self.label.startX = event.x
        self.label.startY = event.y

    def arrastrar2(event):
        x = self.label.winfo_x() - self.label.startX + event.x
        y = self.label.winfo_y() - self.label.startY + event.y

        # Obtiene las dimensiones del frame principal
        frame_width = self.principal_body.winfo_width()
        frame_height = self.principal_body.winfo_height()
        
        # Obtiene las dimensiones del widget
        widget_width = self.label.winfo_width()
        widget_height = self.label.winfo_height()

        # Limita el movimiento dentro del frame
        if 0 <= x <= frame_width - widget_width and 0 <= y <= frame_height - widget_height:
            self.label.place(x=x, y=y)

    def clic(event):
        # Almacena la posición inicial del clic y el tamaño inicial del widget
        self.label.startX = event.x
        self.label.startY = event.y
        self.initial_width = self.label.winfo_width()
        self.initial_height = self.label.winfo_height()
    
    def resize(event):
        # Obtiene las coordenadas del ratón
        y = self.principal_body.winfo_pointery() - self.principal_body.winfo_rooty()

        # Verifica si el clic del mouse está cerca del borde del widget
        if abs(y - self.label.winfo_height()) < 9:
            # Calcula el cambio en la posición del ratón
            delta_y = event.y - self.label.startY

            # Redimensiona la etiqueta en base al cambio en la posición del ratón
            new_height = max(self.initial_height + delta_y, 10) 
            self.label.config(height=new_height)
            
    
    self.label.bind("<Button-1>", arrastrar)
    self.label.bind("<B1-Motion>", arrastrar2)

    # Agrega el evento de redimensionamiento a los bordes de la etiqueta
    self.label.bind("<Button-1>",  clic)
    self.label.bind("<B1-Motion>", resize, add="+")


Hola Ignacio, antes de dar una respuesta me gustaria aclarar una cosa, ¿que función tendrá tu label realmente? El tamaño de los labels se especifica en caracteres, no en pixeles. Si tu Label realmente solo va a contener un color de fondo o una imagen hay widgets mejores, si es para mostrar texto entonces hay que tener en cuenta lo comentado, heigh en Label hace referencia a "cuantos caracteres" no "cuantos pixeles".

Hola, como estas? sinceramente utilice un label por que solo va a tener un nombre y apellido de un cliente, esta enfocado como para hacer una aplicacion de gestion de turnos, y el label tendria el nombre del cliente y en este prodria redimensionar el label en el eje y para agregarle mas tiempo en el turno y podria moverlo libremente si es para pasarlo a otro horario. Pero es un label por que solo mostrara info del cliente, nada mas

Hay dos cosas a tener en cuenta con respecto a tu código:

Debes coordinar los eventos de "movimiento" con los de "redimensionado". Cuando incrementas el tamaño del widget usando el borde inferior no debe modificarse la posición del widget, solo su altura, en cambio, si se redimensiona usando el superior debes modificar ambos.
Siempre se tiene que tener en cuenta que en Tkinter el origen geométrico de un widgets es su esquina superior izquierda y por tanto el eje y incrementa su valor hacia abajo y el eje x hacia la derecha.

La unidad de tamaño  usada en un Label (valores de los parámetros height/width) cuando su contenido es texto es el número de caracteres, no pixeles. Es decir (width=5, height=1) indica 5 caracteres de ancho y uno de alto. Solo se usan pixeles si el Label contiene una imagen.


Esto complica un poco el redimensionar un Label como ocurre en el código que ChatGpt a ̶c̶o̶p̶i̶a̶d̶o̶ generado, ya que no puedes simplemente asignarle una altura en pixeles al Label. Es posible pasar de pixeles a caracteres de forma aproximada usando la fuente (tkinter.font.Font.measure()), pero el Label se redimensionará "a saltos", dado que su incremento de altura será en lineas de texto, no pixel a pixel.
Hay varias formas de conseguir un resultado similar al que buscas, se me ocurre que puedes usar un Frame como base, el cual es simple de resimensionar y luego meter en el lo que quieras, como el Label. Lo único malo de esto es que requiere deshabilitar la propagación de geometría normal de Tkinter para que los hijos no redimensionen al padre.
Algo así:
from enum import Enum
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font


class Side(Enum):
    TOP = 1
    RIGHT = 2
    BOTTOM = 3
    LEFT = 3


class ControlLabel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, text="", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self._inner_label = tk.Label(self, text=text, bg=kwargs.get("bg", ""))
        self._inner_label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.pack_propagate(0)

        font = Font(font=self._inner_label["font"])
        text_width = font.measure(text)
        text_height = font.metrics('linespace')

        self._min_height = max(kwargs.get("height", text_height), text_height)
        self._min_width = max(kwargs.get("width", text_width), text_width)
        self.configure(height=self._min_height, width=self._min_width)

        self.max_side_trigger_dist = 5

        self._start_x = 0
        self._start_y = 0
        self._start_height = 0
        self._start_width = 0
        self._clicked_side = None

        self._inner_label.bind("<Motion>", self.on_mouse_move)
        self._inner_label.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_mouse_drag)

    def on_mouse_drag(self, event):
        x = self.winfo_x()
        y = self.winfo_y()
        height = self.winfo_height()

        match self._clicked_side:
            case Side.TOP:
                bottom_left_y = height + y
                height = min(max(self._min_height, height - event.y), bottom_left_y)
                y = bottom_left_y - height
            case Side.BOTTOM:
                height = min(max(self._min_height, event.y), self.parent.winfo_height() - y)
            case _:
                max_x = self.parent.winfo_width() - self._start_width
                max_y = self.parent.winfo_height() - self._start_height
                x = min(max(0, x - self._start_x + event.x), max_x)
                y = min(max(0, y - self._start_y + event.y), max_y)

        self.place(x=x, y=y, height=height)

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        self._start_x = event.x
        self._start_y = event.y
        self._start_width = self.winfo_width()
        self._start_height = self.winfo_height()

        # Verificar si el click fue en esquinas
        if event.y <= self.max_side_trigger_dist:
            self._clicked_side = Side.TOP
            self.configure(cursor="top_side")

        elif event.y >= self._start_height - self.max_side_trigger_dist:
            self._clicked_side = Side.BOTTOM
            self.configure(cursor="bottom_side")
        else:
            self._clicked_side = None
            self.configure(cursor="hand1")


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.principal_body = tk.Frame(self, bg="moccasin")
        self.principal_body.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=50, pady=50)
        self.principal_body_controls()

    def principal_body_controls(self):
        self.control_label = ControlLabel(
            self.principal_body,
            text="Stack Overflow en Español",
            bg="green",
            width=300,
            height=30
            )
        self.control_label.place(x=100, y=100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x600")
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()


Hago uso del evento <Motion< en vez de capturar el click del botón, esto es algo menos eficiente, pero permite modificar de forma simple la forma del cursor como se aprecia en la imagen.
Para no hacer el código muy extenso, faltan cosas que podrían (o no) ser necesarias. Por ejemplo, actualmente no se puede modificar el texto una vez inicializado widget, pero no es muy complicado de implementar, solo recalcular los nuevos tamaños mínimos. Lo mismo ocurre si el label va a contener texto multilínea.
El código no está probado más allá de la captura mostrada y solo en Linux, si se le va dar un uso "real" aconsejo probarlo más exhaustivamente, los usuarios tienden a encontrar formas de romperlo todo que ni se te pasan por la cabeza al implementar algo...

Te recontra agradezco, estuve buscando por todos lados como solucionar, y no encontraba, me salvaste!

te pregunto, donde puedo estudiar la logica de estos eventos complejos para poder aprender?
